# How to reference python package when filename contains a period

Tags: python, import, module, package, python-import

I am using django and I have a file named models.admin.py and I want to do the following idea in models.py:

```
from "models.admin" import *
```

however, I get a syntax error for having double quotes. But if I just do

```
from models.admin import *
```

then I get "ImportError: No module named admin"

Is there any way to import from a python file that has a period in its name?

Comment: Technically, that's a module, not a package.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Actually, you *can* import a module with an invalid name. But you'll need to use [`imp`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) for that, e.g. assuming file is named `models.admin.py`, you could do

```
import imp
with open('models.admin.py', 'rb') as fp:
    models_admin = imp.load_module(
        'models_admin', fp, 'models.admin.py',
        ('.py', 'rb', imp.PY_SOURCE)
    )
```

But read the docs on [`imp.find_module`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) and [`imp.load_module`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.load_module) before you start using it.

Comment: Bad practice? `imp` is the mechanism behind `import` and `__import__`. More flexibility, but requires more code. Nothing magical about it, though.

Comment: And machine code is the mechanism behind everything. More flexibility and.. see where I'm going? :)

Comment: You obviously need to think twice if you really need to use it, but I don't see how using it is terribly wrong. ;) And it is used in production - see e.g. Trac - http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/trac/loader.py.

Comment: My main point is, that, perhaps it is *not* terribly wrong to use this (ok, my subjective opinion is that it *is* terribly wrong, but away with that), but it is certainly not particularly right to advise it to someone who doesn't quite grasp the concept of modules and packages yet.

Comment: For the record, I never actually named my file that the instant I realized this was going to be complicated. But after Googling out of curiosity and failing to find the answer, I decided that I wanted both the answer (import imp) and the voice of accepted practice (don't use it) to be archived for future Googlers. :)

Comment: I think the important point is that this is an invalid module name as per python style guide: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. However, in OP's case, if module name can't be changed, this solution seems like it is reasonable, as it uses well documented interface. In other words, it is unlikely for a future python minor release to change this behavor. If the solution involved undocumented features, it is a different matter and I would have agreed with shylent.

Comment: To try and make a case for this method of import, consider a naming convention for unit tests whereby code related to testing module x is kept in a file called 'x.test.py'. This works fine most of the time since the unit tests are not normally imported by other modules but if a developer wants to reuse the test for 'x' as the basis for additional testing (ie...maybe they want to test mutlithreaded use of x in a file called 'mtx.test.py') then they would find themselves needing to import 'x.test' which of course only works with the help of the 'imp' module.

Comment: This is formally deprecated as of 3.3.  The correct way is to fiddle with the classes in [`importlib.machinery`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.machinery), which IMHO is *way* more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I am working with a library where a version number has to be in the directory structure (not my choice). Since I have no choice, I need something like this so thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 15):

If you *really* want to, you can import a module with an unusual filename (e.g., a filename containing a '.' before the '.py') using the imp module:

```
>>> import imp
>>> a_b = imp.load_source('a.b', 'a.b.py')
>>> a_b.x
"I was defined in a.b.py!"
```

However, that's generally a bad idea.  It's more likely that you're trying to use packages, in which case you should create a directory named "a", containing a file named "b.py"; and then "import a.b" will load a/b.py.

Comment: `load_source` is obsolete since at least 1.5.

Comment: True, though the non-obsolete way of doing it is quite a bit wordier: a_b = imp.load_module('a.b', open('a.b.py'), os.path.abspath('a.b.py'), ('.py', 'r', imp.PY_SOURCE))

Answer (score 4):

The file is called `models/admin.py`. ([Source](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/models/admin.py?rev=945))

That is, it should be called `admin.py` in a directory called `models`.

Then you can import using `from models.admin import *`, assuming that it is in your Python path.

Answer (score 4):

Like below

Assume dir structure is like this:

```
C:.
│   script.py
│   
└───Parent
    └───Child
        ├───1.1
        │       main.py
        │       
        └───1.2
```

**assume you want to import main.py in script.py **

**your main.py looks like below**

```
def my_function():
  print("Hello from a function")
```

**your script.py looks like below**

```
from os import path
import importlib
from os.path import dirname
import sys
import importlib.util


def getPath():
    # your logic to get to the path
    return path.join(dirname(__file__),'Parent','Child','1.1','main.py')

file_path = getPath() 
module_name = 'main'

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

#call functions like this
module.my_function()
```

Check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/SciTechEnthusiast/25f27765180c6811ca1ce4165317e8ea)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't import a python file as a module if its name contains a period (or a question mark, or exclamation mark, etc). A python module's name (not including the .py) must be a valid python name (ie can be used as a variable name).

Comment: Do you have a reference handy for this?

Comment: The reference is the Python grammar spec (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html). However, this actually only specifies what is allowed for the import statement -- as pointed out above in the accepted answer, it's technically possible to get around this by using the underlying import mechanisms.

Comment: What would be the best pattern for long names with multiple words? Naming a package, and thus a  folder "awesome.project" will create issues, while "awesomeProject" seems an anti-pattern. Not sure I get this rule correctly: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#id87

Comment: Actually you can, see @SciTech Enthusiast answer

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using `grafanalib`, and the filename has to be `xx.dashboard.py` based on the [doc](https://grafanalib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#generating-dashboards). However, I do want to import this file to simplify the uploading step.

I got warning when I use `import imp`:

> the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses

Here is the simple demo using `importlib` and `pathlib`:

`foo.bar.py` and `main.py` are in the same foler.

```
# foo.bar.py

num = 42
```

```
# main.py

import importlib.machinery
import pathlib

module = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(
    "foo_bar",
    pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("foo.bar.py").resolve().as_posix(),
).load_module()
print(module.num)  # 42
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not referencing *files* in the import statement, you are referencing *modules* and *packages*.

Please read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html), they are very clear on that matter.

Anyway, since you are using django, the usual approach won't work. If you want to keep models in separate files, rather than in models.py, you have to take extra steps, outlined, for example, [here](http://paltman.com/2008/jan/29/breaking-apart-models-in-django/).

Edit:
Well, I don't really know what the questioneer means when he mentions admin and whether or not it is related to the admin interface of django. My points still stand.

Comment: A module is a file. To quote the docs you referenced: `To support this, Python has a way to put definitions in a file and use them in a script or in an interactive instance of the interpreter. Such a file is called a module;`