# is there a nice "python conventions and best practices" summary anywhere?

Tags: python, conventions

I am fairly new to python, and I generally code as a means to an end, as opposed to being a "coder".  I like all the power that python contains through libraries, and I enjoy the inherent but invisible strength in python.  (E.g., object-oriented, but still relatively scripter-friendly structure for making classes, etc.)
    But I keep running into cases where I cannot find complete documentation, and I find pointers to the appropriate documentation only **after** discovering the problem I have accidentally created.  So far, I have only found references to the following appropriate documentation:

[PEP 0008](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
[PEP 0257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

Unless I missed something, however, neither of these captured issues regarding "proper" python file naming conventions.  After making several python scripts, I discovered that I am not supposed to use periods ( . ) in the file name, since it will make it a challenge to import them.  After running into this problem, I could indeed find links talking to this point:

[no periods allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828127/how-to-reference-python-package-when-filename-contains-a-period)

However, I'd really like to start tackling issues pro-actively, instead of having to step backwards through the proper mechanisms.  Python has SEVERAL aspects which make it quite unique (such as required whitespace & the aforementioned disallowed periods in filenames).  I am too new to say whether these are good things or bad things.  But I can say that it is a pain to keep discovering all these things after the fact.

Is there any sort of "encyclopedia" which may capture all these idiosyncrasies, beyond the 2 relatively brief documents I've cited above?

Thanks, all!
                      Mike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any definitive source that covers *everything* but in addition to the links you already posted you should definitely check these links out for some best practices:

- [Google Python Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html)
- [PythonStyleGuide](http://code.google.com/p/soc/wiki/PythonStyleGuide)

These cover style and also highlight some gotchas that can be avoided by using certain conventions and patterns.

Comment: Note: with due respect to Google, 80 character lines drive me nuts. My screen is wider than it is tall and I had having a tall, skinny column of code that I have to constantly scroll through. Use 4 spaces and reasonably long lines and people with modern screens will love you.

Answer (score 3):

I *really* like [Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) article by David Goodger.