# Importing a module into python with a period in the path

Tags: python, import, period

I'm having trouble importing numpy into my script because of some path-name issues.

I'm running my script with python 2.7, rather than the default 2.6 on my server because I need some of the updates in the Collections module. I cant seem to import numpy like:

```
from numpy.random import poisson
```

So I am trying to use the python2.7 specific links to numpy on my server, which are installed in:
    /opt/lib/python2.7/numpy

But this period in the path is really making this difficult. I cannot change the path in anyway.

I've found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828127/how-to-reference-python-package-when-filename-contains-a-period), but frankly the code just doesn't make enough sense to me for me to feel safe using it (plus several commenters seemed to suggest it was a bad idea.). If someone has another suggestion, or if you can give me a good explanation of the code there I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting PYTHONPATH to point to `/opt/lib/python2.7`, after which `import numpy` et cetera should pull libraries from there.

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/opt/lib/python2.7 python27 my_script.py
```