# How do I import all modules in a package that contains a dot in its name?

Tags: python

[This linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828249/429533) tells me how to import a **single module** with a dot in its name, but how do I import all modules from a **package** with a dot in its name:

```
from package.with.dot.in.name import *
```

where my files look something like:

```
package.with.dot.in.name/
    __init__.py
    module_1.py
    module_2.py
```

---

I know that having dots in a package name is wrong. It's there because Sikuli requires your "project" to be named "{project}.sikuli".

Comment: @DavidReeve that's the question I specifically mention in my question. It doesn't answer my question, because it talks about loading a single **module**.

Comment: @PauloScardine my question **is not** a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: You can import packages using `imp.load_module`. You'd just have to reference them through the package name (`package_with_dot_in_name.function()`). See the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html?highlight=imp#imp.load_module

Comment: You can't.  You should import the individual modules instead.  If you want a package with a functional `__init__.py` etc., don't put dots in the name of the directory.  If you can't get Sikuli to work with that, ask a question *about Sikuli*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in no way I would encourage this behavior, you can do this by updating your `locals()` via a reference to it with the internal dictionary of attributes from the module you imported:

```
>>> r = __import__('requests')
>>> l = locals()
>>> l.update(r.__dict__)
>>> locals()['cookies']
<module 'requests.cookies' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.pyc'>
```

Or, put another way:

```
>>> cookies
<module 'requests.cookies' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.pyc'>
```

Edit: using Jace's self-answer below, the following will work for filenames with dots:

```
name = 'package.with.dot.in.name'
pathname, description = imp.find_module(name)[1:]
package = imp.load_module(name, None, pathname, description)
locals().update(package.__dict__)
```

Comment: Won't `__import__('package.with.dot.in.name')` attempt to treat the dots as separators?

Comment: I don't believe so, but I didn't have a module around to test with.  As long as you're using _some process_ that will return a reference (e.g. `<module 'some.module' from...>`, you can continue on with the rest of my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554769/how-do-i-import-all-modules-in-a-package-that-contains-a-dot-in-its-name/27555386#27555386) and some of the comments, I was able to do:

```
name = 'package.with.dot.in.name'
pathname, description = imp.find_module(name)[1:]
package = imp.load_module(name, None, pathname, description)
locals().update(package.__dict__)
```

Comment: Cheers -- updated my answer to include the imp portion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, like almost everything in Python, the import system is hack-able. You just need to create a custom loader and register it at `sys.meta_path` (for details see [PEP 302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#specification-part-1-the-importer-protocol)).

Lets say you want to hack the import system in order to load "foo.bar" if you import "foo_dot_bar":

```
# search folder "foo.bar" and load it as a package
from foo_dot_bar import *
```

Be warned: this is just a starting point for you, it is not a fully tested solution; in fact it is way beyond my wizardry level!

```
# stupid_dot_importer.py
import os
import imp
import sys

class StupidDotPackageLoader(object):
    @staticmethod
    def _get_real_name(name):
        return ".".join(name.split('_dot_'))
    def find_module(self, name, path=None):
        try:
            imp.find_module(self._get_real_name(name))
        except ImportError:
            return None
        return self
    def load_module(self, name):
        _, pathname, description = imp.find_module(self._get_real_name(name))
        return imp.load_module(self._get_real_name(name), None, pathname, description)
```

Suppose you have the following structure:

```
foo.bar
   |
   +--- __init__.py 
   |
   +--- module1.py
   |
   +--- module2.py
```

And:

```
$ cat foo.bar/__init__.py
from module1 import *
from module2 import *

$ cat foo.bar/module1.py
foo = 'bar'

$ cat foo.bar/module2.py
spam = 'eggs'
```

Then magic:

```
>>> from stupid_dot_importer import *
>>> sys.meta_path = [StupidDotPackageLoader()]
>>> from foo_dot_bar import *
>>> foo
'bar'
>>> spam
'eggs'
>>>
```