# How do I import a module in a package / folder with a dot in the filename for a relative import?

Tags: python, python-import

my file organization

[image]

problem:

sikuli includes `.sikuli` as name of folder and doesn't seem to support multiple script files within one folder

I want to re-use functions from duel.py in duel_all.py

Answer (score 0):

use shell util to copy the file over and use it

```
import shutil
from os.path import join, dirname, basename
__dirname = dirname(__file__)
shutil.copy(join(__dirname, '..', 'duel.sikuli', 'duel.py'), join(__dirname, 'duel.py'))

from duel import duel
```

---

or check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/27556208/3854436