# How to import double extension files in python

Tags: python, python-import

I have a python file called

```
default.properties.py
```

How can I successfully import it as a module, I tried

```
import default.properties as prop
```

but it didn't work until I changed the name to default.py, Id like to keep the name with two extensions, is this possible?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828127/how-to-reference-python-package-when-filename-contains-a-period)

Comment: naming conventions highly advise against using periods in the filename, underscores instead should be used. i understand if this is someone else's module that you had no choice, just future reference

Answer (score 3):

You can use `imp`

```
import imp
mymodule = imp.load_source('default.properties','default.properties.py')
>>>mymodule.variable
"i am variable in default.properties.py"
```

**OR**

```
mymodule = imp.load_module('default.properties',
                            open('default.properties.py'),
                            os.path.abspath('default.properties.py'),
                            ('.py', 'r', imp.PY_SOURCE))
>>>mymodule.variable
"i am variable in default.properties.py"
```

Comment: In Python 3.1, it's `mymodule = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('default.properties', 'default.properties.py').load_module()`.  In Python 3.4, `load_module()` was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

File names can only have one extension. Your file has extension `py`. The base name is `default.properties`.

You want to write

```
import default.properties
```

That is possible, but it requires that you make a [package](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#packages) named `default` and a submodule of that package named `properties`.

Note that this involves making a directory named `default` containing files named `__init__.py` and `properties.py`.

You cannot import, using the import statement, a module in a file whose base name contains a period. That's because the file's base name must be a valid Python identifier.

In other words, you can't name your file `default.properties.py` but you can use the package mechanism to allow you to write

```
import default.properties
```