# How Can I Import A Python 3 Module With A Period In The Filename?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, filenames, python-importlib

What is the proper way to import a script that contains a period, such as program_1.4.py, ideally using importlib?

(Now that the imp module is deprecated, this this answer no longer applies: [How to reference python package when filename contains a period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828127/how-to-reference-python-package-when-filename-contains-a-period) .)

Comment: Take note that the proper way is most certainly either to fix the module by renaming it, or to run it as an executable as it was meant to be.

Comment: As one of the answers to the linked question says, this is not possible.

Comment: @Seth Of course it is possible: Python is Turing-complete. There may not be a very Dutch solution, but I am looking for the simplest, lowest-overhead answer I can get for this real-world use case where stand-alone programs (non-local, read-only, etc—so no renaming) are linked together as part of a larger application.

Comment: @JBT Even though importing these files is possible, in general, just because a language is Turing complete doesn't mean that it can do anything - it just means it can run any algorithm, but not that it can to import certain file types. Take, for example, a Turing machine: it is by definition Turing complete, but it can't import any files because that's not part of the semantics (and it was invented before computers...).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference python package when filename contains a period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828127/how-to-reference-python-package-when-filename-contains-a-period)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the CPython quite a lot and coming back to some other solutions (especially [Import arbitrary python source file. (Python 3.3+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-arbitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3/19011259#19011259)), I realized that I needed to pass the full path to my module. Here is the cross-platform, call-location-independent solution:

"""

```
import os, sys # For running from Notepad++ shortcut, etc
import importlib.machinery

program_1_4 = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('program_1.4', os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'program_1.4.py')).load_module()

print(program_1_4)
program_1_4.main()
```

"""

Comment: I posted a new solution using `importlib` and `pathlib` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74609764/2000548 The reason using `pathlib` instead of `os` is at [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/dont-use-python-os-library-any-more-when-pathlib-can-do-141fefb6bdb5)

Comment: @HongboMiao That also works (same principle), but I'd stick with `"""os"""` because it provides a lower-overhead approach. Avoid objects when strings suffice. More secure, too.